# Any alternative to this code?

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have tried many things to make this code work, it consists of showing an AlertDialog/description when taping on an element/marker from map. The problem is that 3 of 4 markers work (but not showing the right description. it looks like the previous one) and the last force closes the app with the logcat error:

`CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 requested, with a size of 4`

**Code:**

```
@Override
        protected boolean onTap(int index) {
            db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            String[] columns_descri = new String[] {COL_DESCRI};

            Cursor cur = db.query(true, TABLE_COORD, columns_descri,null, null, null, null, null, null);

            cur.moveToPosition(index);
                String description = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_DESCRI));

                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Geo.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Infos.");
                dialog.setMessage(description);
                dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {    
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();

             cur.close();
             db.close();

            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not use directly index, instead, you probably have an adapter somewhere that can give you either the object you want to display or the _id of your row, which you can use to forge a precise request

### edit

You are using a ItemizedOverlay. Therefore, you can get the tapped item by :

```
public void onTap(int index) {
    Item item = getItem(index);
}
```

Then I suppose you can get the relevant informations from the item rather than from a cursor.

Comment: I'm really not understanding your answer. Can you post an example code please ?

Comment: And for the cursor query that outputs the column "Description" that will have the content of AlertDialogs ? I delete it ? and how to indicate that the AlertDialog have to point in that element and show its description?

Comment: The Item class is one of your own, I assume, therefore you probably know if there is a description in it, or an id that refers to the row in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `cur.moveToPosition(index - 1);`

Comment: Made it, but same problem, the marker that cause a FC just switches to another one.